# How to make GIT completely forget about some file content and replace it with something new?

Tags: git, gitlab

## Context

I'm using GitLab and maintain some UTF-16 LE encoded INI file in some repo. Downloading that file using TortoiseGIT looks good, I see the BOM, the text looks good in VSCode, that recognizes that file as UTF-16 LE with the expected newlines of CRLF etc. The problem is when downloading some ZIP archive GitLab is able to generate.

In those cases that one file gets all bytes of 0x0A getting replaced to 0x0D0A, actually changing LF to CRLF. The problem is that it's not needed at all, because the file properly contains CRLF already following UTF 16 LE encoding. Even if it was necessary, changing one byte to two only is wrong for UTF-16 LE as well, it's missing the additional 0x00 per byte this way. In the end, the result can't be rendered properly.

[image: Wrong rendering in VSCode]

[image: Wrong rendering in some other editor, too many lines]

[image: Wrong newline bytes]

[image: Wrong newline bytes]

## Updating `.gitattributes` doesn't help

At first I've committed the file wrongly, because I expected it to be encoded using `windows-1252`. The following rule applied:

```
*       text=auto
*.ini   text eol=crlf working-tree-encoding=windows-1252
```

I've change that to the following, executed `git add --renormalize .`, committed, pushed and things seem to work OK:

```
*       text=auto
*.ini   text eol=crlf working-tree-encoding=windows-1252

0x0409.ini diff -text -working-tree-encoding
/Driver-DalsaFG/77593-Teledyne_Dalsa_Xcelera_CL_LX1_device_driver/0x0409.ini diff -text -working-tree-encoding
```

The web-UI showed contents of the file now and I was able to download that one individual file with proper line endings and encoding. That wasn't the case before. Though, generating a ZIP for some branch using the web-UI or the API still doesn't work with the above problems of the file content.

## Known issues at GitLab

- [Gitlab has problems handling ansi files e.g. windows-1252 characters. This also results in merges or "online edits" deleting chars](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/34874)
- [Support diffs of UTF-16 encoded text files](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16556)

I wanted to add an additional issue for this problem at GitLab and they suggested to create a repo to demonstrate the problem as part of issue reporting. So I did that and recognized to my surprise that the problem didn't occur in the repo. The only thing I did was creating the repo, cloning it, adding my files as-is, committing and pushing. Though, the file in the downloaded ZIP looked OK. So I tried the same with a new repo in my GitLab and the same happened as well, the file in the ZIP was OK.

## Additional commits make ALL existing data fail

The strange thing is the following: When I commit the exactly same file again in an additional subdir with correct `.gitattributes`, the file is correct in the ZIP. If the `.gitattributes` for the file in the subdir ONLY are wrong, ALL other same files are wrong in the ZIP as well. In some test cases I was able to fix this by simply making the `.gitattributes` correct again and apply to all files, but in some test cases this wasn't sufficient. The test happened in different repos, one created newly and the other one containing the data of actual interest.

As GIT tracks content by its hashes instead of paths, I have the feeling it might decide to use the same wrong data available at the server repo when creating ZIPs and I'm unable to get it to decide otherwise. If `.gitattributes` only would make the difference when creating the ZIP, I would be able to switch between a working and non-working file only by committing those changes. But I'm not, only in some test cases this seems to help.

## Question

Is there any way to overwrite the GIT-internal data maintained at GitLab with what's available locally? Pretty much like a force push, but even in cases the client doesn't have any actual changes committed. Because the changes to `.gitattribute` don't result in changes in my working copy, even `git add --renormalize .` doesn't make any difference. Most likely because the file is automatically used as binary at some point.

Thanks!

Comment: I've setup the non-working repo as remote in the working repo, fetched all branches, pushed all the data to the working repo and tried multiple non-working branches of the non-working repo in the working one. All of those worked instantly and provided a working INI file within the ZIP. Without any additional commits or other changes. Isn't that a bit strange?

Comment: A UTF-16-LE file is *binary*, to Git. Use `*.ini binary` to tell it that, or at least, `*.ini -text`. Note that `git archive` pays attention to the to-be-archived commit's `.gitattributes` by default; you'll ned `--worktree-attributes` (is a clone in which you fiddle with the .gitattributes file in the working tree) to override that.

Comment: Unfortunately, since it's GitLab (at gitlab.com?) that's generating the zip file by running `git archive`, you won't have enough control to make them do that, but you can experiment locally.

Comment: `*.ini binary` is wrong in my use-case as most INIs aren't UTF-16 LE. The web-UI of GitLab seems able to render and download that file with my mentioned settings. It's not only when NOT having `-working-tree-encoding`, in which case I can see a UTF-8 encoded BOM in the file and that most likely makes the web-UI think the file is binary, while for GIT it isn't.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that there's no reliable setting which prevents wrong translation of LF to CRLF currently. Sometimes in some (empty?) repo things work as expected, while some additional commits with the same file NOT properly covered by rules in `.gitattributes` male ALL of the same file in the same repo fail. Removing the one committed, not covered file sometimes make ALL other files work again, sometimes it doesn't. PULLing that new repo into another repo sometimes makes the same files there work as well, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Things are simply not reliable for some reason and it looks to me that server side content tracking of same content differently encoded for the same file is the problem somehow. There might be some wrong normalization applied for some files with the same content resulting in one and the same wrong representation at the server for ALL of those files, even some would be handled correctly otherwise. Seems difficult to get server side data corrected in those cases and hence the might ZIP might get created with wrong assumptions or base data to work with.